# How in mvc can I submit a text box that is part of the universal html head template and include two text boxes from the page below the template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I'm new to razor and mvc. So i'm sorry if I worded this oddly, but basically I have a search box on my partial view and then in the view for the page I have a few drop down boxes to further limit the search. I can submit them all together in the local form but when I split them up and have the search in the top form i'm not sure how to submit all the fields together?

Comment: Can you show your markup? I suspect some fields are outside your form tags.